# Disable chrome history for an android app built with a website

Tags: javascript, android, firebase

I am developing an android app starting from a website and encapsulated with TWA (trusted web activity).
The app works, but the problem is that on the chrome history I find all the app addresses visited.
And that's not very good for the security. How can I do to prevent chrome from saving my history?
Is there any javascript or other language function?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for the [`chrome.history` API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/history/). From the link:

> Use the `chrome.history` API to interact with the browser's record of visited pages. You can add, remove, and query for URLs in the browser's history.